# Best way to reduce length of || (or) operator?

Tags: javascript, function, if-statement, dry, comparison-operators

I was wondering if there's a best way to reduce comparison operator when using `if else` statement in JavaScript.

Suppose we have a simple function like this:

```
let txt = ["a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z"];

let collect_vowels = [];

txt.forEach( letter => {
    if (letter === 'a' || letter === 'e' || letter === 'i' || letter === 'o' || letter === 'u') {
        collect_vowels.push(letter);
    }
});
```

As you can see, we have very long `||` operator inside of `if`. I want to know if there's a better (shorter) way to write it.

Comment: `['a','e','i','o','u'].includes(letter)`

Comment: `if(~'aeiou'.indexOf(letter)){...}`